# High CPU when I open nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, cpu

Everything else works fine but when I open my home folder or move stuff around in it my cpu gets really high and everything slows down.

This started to happen after upgrading to 11.10. Everything in 11.04 worked fine.

Does anybody know why?

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Are u using Ubuntu One? I notice the same when I'm uploading a big map. It asks a lot of memory and slows Nautilus down.

Comment: What processor do you have? You can find out by going to System Info in the Dash Home. If you have a lower end processor the reason is it can't process enough calculations fast enough. The other reason could be that you don't have enough ram post to let us know. Jake

Comment: What processor do you have? You can find out by going to System Info in the Dash Home. If you have a lower end processor the reason is it can't process enough calculations fast enough. The other reason could be that you don't have enough ram post to let us know. Jake

Comment: Memory: 2.0 GiB, Processor: Intel Core 2CPU T7200@2.00GHz*2, Graphics: Intel 945GMx86, OS type: 32bit, Disk:490GB

Comment: Nope not using UbuntuOne

Comment: Hmm I don't see a hardware reason for why it makes things really slow perhaps you could try going to System Monitor and look for Nautilus and change the priority to a lower one.

Comment: Do you have ClamAV installed? It includes a Nautilus plugin which used to make my CPU usage shoot up as well every time I opened Nautilus.<br />
Also, does it only occur when you open Nautilus with Unity? Or does it also happen if you start it from a terminal?

Comment: Nope I dont have ClamAV (unless its default). Yup, using `code`alias browse='nautilus'`code` cpu spikes when moving things around

Comment: Strange, got any proprietary drivers installed? Also, can we have the output of `dmesg` (put it on Pastebin)?

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/mcA6kkdA

Comment: I see a couple of strange things in there, but I don't know what to do with them... Maybe someone else does?

Comment: @jesse Please edit your post to include new information rather than replying directly in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you find out which program is spiking the CPU you can't solve the problem. Use a system monitor such as `System Monitor` or `htop` to see which program is responsible for consuming your CPU. It might be Nautilus, or it might be something else.

In my case, Compiz eats a lot of CPU. The only solution I've found is to run an environment that doesn't use Compiz, such as Unity 2D or Gnome Shell.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using Marlin and its been working great.

Answer (score 0):

Used htop to get a much better view of what's going on than top was able to provide.  Quickly figured out that the streaming audio that I had going was causing it.  Closed that browser tab (switched over to using the same stream on my smartphone), and voila!  I can use my laptop again at an acceptable rate.